# Retried Operation with generic Exception

Tags: java, exceptions, generics

I am looking for a way to get the logic of retrying an operation in a single method while keeping the exception types of the operation.

I.e., the implementation to retry an operation could look like this:

```
public void retriedOperation(Operable operable, int maxAttempts) throws Exception {
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {
        try {
            operable.doOperation();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (attempt + 1 > maxAttempts) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation is however only capable of throwing an unspecified `Exception` and thereby looses lots of information.

Unfortunately, generic Exceptions can <strike>neither be caught nor thrown</strike> not be caught in Java, thus something like

```
public void <ExceptionType extends Exception> retriedOperation(...) throws ExceptionType { ... }
```

would only allow to catch an unspecific Exception, check if it is of the right type and then cast it. But if it is of another type, it cannot be thrown with this method header.

**Is there a way to implement a generic retry function that preserves specific exceptions?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately, generic Exceptions can neither be caught nor thrown in Java, thus something like ... is not possible.

Change that to:

```
public void <T extends Exception> retriedOperation(...) throws T { ... }
```

And it should work just fine. When `T` is a checked exception, the compiler will complain appropriately. E.g.

```
obj.<IOException>retriedOperation(...);
```

Will force the surrounding method to either handle IOException or declare that it throws it. However, as long as `Operable` specifies that it throws `Exception`, your code won't work, since the method would have to check if the caught exception is of a particular type it doesn't yet know. The real solution is to change `Operable` to specify whatever exception it throws:

```
class Operable<T extends Exception>
```

And now you can rewrite your method as

```
public <T extends Exception> void retriedOperation(Operable<T> operable, ...) throws T {
    ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof RuntimeException) {
            throw (RuntimeException) e;
        } else {
            throw (T) e;
        }
    }
    ...
 }
```

And everything will work just fine, provided `Operable` only throws one kind of checked exception. If you need to handle more than one, the solution will get a bit ugly - <s>you'll have to pass a list of class tokens as an argument and check if the caught exception is of a compatible type for any of them.</s> (In retrospect, this wouldn't work as described. You *do* need class tokens, but you'd need an overload of the method for 2 exceptions, 3 exceptions, etc to get the `throws` clause right.)

Finally, it seems to me `retriedOperation` should be a static method.

Comment: I actually tried it that way, but there is still an unchecked cast involved: since an Exception of generic type cannot be caught, an unspecified `Exception` needs to be caught and then cast to the generic `T` type. This presents a problem when the Exception is not of type `T` because we cannot throw it.

Comment: @Mash Sorry about that, see my edit.

Comment: I think, there should also be another catch-block that catches RuntimeExceptions and re-throws them before the catch-block with the general Exception.

Comment: See my new edit. If you catch `Exception` and cast, it'll work, provided the caught exception is of the advertised type.

Comment: Yes but since the `Operable<T>` is still capable of throwing unchecked RuntimeExceptions that are not of the generic type, these should be handled explicitly to avoid cast-errors.

Comment: After all, this approach is still pretty inflexible when it comes to more than one Exception.
I'll probably end up repeating the retry-code most of the times because of this limitation (i.e. declaring a second Exception that gets thrown without retrying does not work without providing a Class parameter of this Exception).

Comment: @Mash I've fixed it so that it'll pass RuntimeExceptions through. I can edit it later with a version that catches an arbitrary number of checked exceptions, but that one isn't as simple to use because of the type tokens. Honestly, checked exceptions don't mesh well with this kind of functional idiom.

Comment: Is there a possibility to catch an arbitrary number of Exceptions as well as keeping the method signature to the specified Exceptions only? I thought this would only be possible by passing a `Class<T extends Exception>` array but then the method header would have to be changed to `throws Exception`.

Comment: @Mash Now that I think about it some more, you're right; I don't think it's possible to do it with a single method. You'd need implementations for 2, 3, ..., `n` checked exceptions. This is why I said checked exceptions don't play nice with functional idioms. They're functionally the same as changing the return type of your method to be `Either<R, E1, E2, ...>` where `R` is the original return type and `En` are exception types, but because there is no such `Either` type it's really hard to compose functions that make use of them.

Comment: Yes indeed, there is no real functionality provided for this use case (something like varags generics could do the trick but that doesn't really make sense).

A better approach might be to leave out all the generics, throw an Exception and handle specific Exceptions outside the retry-method with instanceof blocks.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a java developer, but this might work for you anyway.

You can try using the `instanceof` operator.

```
public void retriedOperation<T>(Operable operable, int maxAttempts) throws Exception {
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++) {
        try {
            operable.doOperation();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (!(e instanceof T) || attempt + 1 > maxAttempts) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `T` is the type of the exception you want to allow.

Comment: That's better in the way that only specific exceptions get caught.
Unfortunately, it's still an unspecific `Exception` that gets thrown.

Comment: It will re-throw whatever exception was originally thrown.

Comment: @Matthew: Because of Java's checked exceptions, specifying "throws Exception" requires the /call site/ to handle `Exception`, too. The moment you have anything that throws Exception you have to break the exception model to write sane code.

Comment: That won't work. [Java's type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) means you can't use a generic parameter for instantiating objects, getting the `Class` information, or checking type with `instanceof` at runrime...